# How to cover a for loop in Apex Test?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

the for loop is not being covered... I would like to know why. Thanks!

Here the test:

```
     @IsTest public static void testSaveDistriverloren()
    {
    Priority_Distribution__c fetchPd = new Priority_Distribution__c(distriVerloren__c = 
    FALSE, Products_list__c='Lucky Strike Original', Item_Number__c=2003);

    insert fetchPd;

    Boolean distri = TRUE;

    Priority_Distribution__c checkDistriVerloren = new Priority_Distribution__c();
    checkDistriVerloren= [SELECT distriVerloren__c FROM Priority_Distribution__c WHERE 
    Item_Number__c=2003 AND Account__r.Id =: fetchPd.Account__r.Id];
    checkDistriVerloren.distriVerloren__c = distri;
    update checkDistriVerloren;
    Test.startTest();
        try {
            PriorityTableController.saveDistriVerloren(distri, 2003, fetchPd.Account__r.Id);
        } catch (Exception ex){}
   Test.stopTest();
}
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to uncover what's happening?  Have you checked the variables to see what value they have?  This will tell you exactly why you don't have coverage

Answer (score 1):

I see you haven't created test data for the object Priority_List_Distribution__c in your test class.

Adding following lines of code in the test class, would cover the class fully:

```
Priority_List_Distribution__c PrLDistri = new Priority_List_Distribution__c();
insert PrLDistri;
```

Result with simple example:
[image: result]

See similar [thread and discussion](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MJ3vIAG)